# Android Change ListView row width to match screen width on very wide screens

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a `ListView` using custom row layout, each composed of 6 `TextView` widgets horizontally.
Each row is wider that most phones screens, even if in landscape mode.
But on some high end tablets, the row width is shorter than the landscape screen width.

***How can I detect the screen is wider that the `ListView` row, and then change the width of the last `TextView` widget to match the screen width?***

I don't want to make the rows wider *by default*, because they would be **too wide** for normal devices.
I've tried to check the widths in the `ListView` adapter `getView()` method, but there all widths are 0, even the `convertView` width, event after layout inflation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/log_time"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textSize="14sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/log_level"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textSize="14sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/log_pid"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textSize="14sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/log_tid"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textSize="14sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/log_tag"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="14sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/log_message"
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="14sp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml for row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encapsulate all of your `TextViews` within a `RelativeLayout`, then use `RelativeLayout`'s alignment attributes to make the last element fill the remaining screen space.

For example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The second `TextView` is set to align to the right of the first one, and to align to it's parent's right edge. Thus it will fill any space between the first `TextView` and the end of the `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Wouldn't that align the last element to fill the remaining space on ALL devices? I need to fill the remaining space only on very wide screens, on all the other screens I want to keep the width I set on the XML (by the way, the last TextView is set to 600dp width, I want to keep it unless on a very wide screen)

Comment: In that case, you can put this XML in a targeted layout folder. Perhaps something along the lines of layout-sw600dp/whatever.xml will do the trick. I would recommend reading the [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) page from the Android Developers Guide to select an appropriate layout folder.